# Possibly overlapping tags with [mental-stimulation]

Tags: discussion, tags

The tags [toys](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) and [play](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play) seem to heavily overlap with [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation). Are all three necessary, or can [toys](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) and [play](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play) be merged into [mental-stimulation](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mental-stimulation)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that [play](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play) should, but I think [toys](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toys) are different, or can be about the physical object itself rather than the purpose.

Comment: "Play" could also be about physical stimulation rather than mental, e.g. helping a pet contend with arthritis or just get more exercise.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Very true. Hmm... makes me wonder if we should leave it for a while instead.

Comment: Leave it alone.